# WordPress wp_get_current_user() return empty array in Other php function

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-5, integration

I am using WordPress user in my Laravel 5.2 application. User logged in WordPress. I can get easily user data in WordPress. But when I try to get user in Laravel 5.2 it's sending empty array 
i.e

```
  WP_User Object
  (
    [data] => stdClass Object ( )

[ID] => 0
[caps] => Array
    (
    )

[cap_key] => 
[roles] => Array
    (
    )

[allcaps] => Array
    (
    )

    [filter] => 
)
```

Here us my function WordPress function.php

```
add_action('init', 'loginFunction');
function loginFunction(){
     return wp_get_current_user();  
}
```

In Laravel route

```
Route::get('/wordpress', function(){
    require('wordpress1\wp-load.php');
    echo "<pre>"; print_r(loginFunction());
});
```

Comment: `Route::get('/wordpress', function(){
    require('wordpress1\wp-load.php');
    echo "<pre>"; print_r(wp_get_current_user());
});`
Have you tried that one? Can you tell me what output does it generate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Route::get('/wordpress', function(){
require('wordpress/wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;
echo "<pre>"; print_r(loginFunction());
});
```